# How to count rows in grid, but only with true flag?

Tags: extjs, grid

For example I have a grid with some data:

```
ID | name | is_active
1  | lala |     1
2  | 1ala |     1
3  | 2ala |     1
4  | 3ala |     0
```

I want to `getCount()` of those elements that have true flag: In my case there will be 3.

```
Active = 3
Inactive = 1
```

How to count this in extjs grid?

Comment: store.filter then store.count

Comment: I am curious why this question was initially one down. We should add comment about what is wrong so that we can all improve quesitons.

Answer (score 1):

You can use query method of store to filter out required records based on any property, this is done on the fly and filtering is not permanently applied on store

```
var store = gridpanel.getStore();
var collection = store.query('is_active', 1);
return collection.getCount();
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use this idea:

```
var total = 0;
store.each(function(r){
    if(r.data.is_active) {
        total++;
    }
});
```

Comment: why is 'var total' in the beginning?

Comment: @JohhnyGalovecki thanks :) `count` variable wasn't correct. Must be `total`.